# How can I add a logo through CSS?

Tags: php, css

How can I add my logo into my css stylesheet as I have tons of php pages and I dont want to manually add in one by one.

Basically I wan to have a global function so I just need to put in one page.

Answer (score 4):

In css use `background` as below.

```
.logo { background : url(path_to_logo); }
```

Answer (score 2):

Or if your logo was say 60px high you could  do

```
body { 
padding:60px 0 0 0:
background-image : url(path_to_logo) no-repeat top left; 
}
```

Adding the logo to every body tag (common to every page

Ideally you would have a header.php file which you include in every page - by using

```
include('header.php');
```

Then any changes you make to this file will take effect throughout your site, such as adding

```
<h1>Site title</h1>
<img src="logo.jpg">
```

Answer (score 1):

just make a header include and include it on the top of every page?

Answer (score 1):

Add

```
<div class="logo"> </div>
```

in your header.

Add this to your stylesheet:

```
.logo { width: Zpx; height: Ypx; background-image: (pathtoimage.gif); }
```

Specifying your width and height diameters of course :)